# How to change the opacity of a given text periodically after some interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want change the opacity of text periodically after some interval. The opacity should changed from 30% to 100% in a loop after some time interval.

I have used:

`$("#mydiv").animate({opacity:1.0},2000);`

but cant get it in loop.

Comment: It sounds like you want the same text to periodically get an opacity of 100%, which can't be what you mean. Do you have divs to change (one every few seconds), or do you want the opacity to toggle between 30% and 100% every few seconds, or something completely different?

Comment: yes i want to toggle between 30% to 100% but periodically

Comment: You can use css for that , why using JQuery and animation

Comment: can you please guide me out

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by css:

```
#mydiv {
    animation-name: periodicfading;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes periodicfading {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that there are other browsers other than webkit out there, and that they too support animations?

Comment: @some Thank you for notifying me, will add the support of all browsers

Comment: What I meant it that you do not need to prefix it. `@keyframes`, `animation`, `animation-*` etc, without webkit is working.

Comment: Ok you're right, i'll keep it simple, this way is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css opacity animation for the div and then add this code

.myID{

animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of how to change opacity over time using `setInterval`.

I leave it to you to continue the "loop" instead of ending it when we reach 100%. (As a hint, you can write a similar function called "lighten" and use a boolean called "gettingDarker" to help decide which function to call.)

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); // Gets a reference to the div
let opacity = 0.3; // Initializes the JavaScript variable
myDiv.style.opacity = opacity; // Initializes the div's opacity

// Calls `darken` every 500ms
// (Identifies `ticker` so we could later pass it to `clearInterval`)
const ticker = setInterval(darken, 500);

function darken(){
  console.log(opacity);
  if(opacity < 1){
    opacity += 0.1; // Increases the value
    myDiv.style.opacity = opacity; // Applies the new value to the div
  }
  else{ // Already 100% opaque, so stop calling the function
    clearInterval(ticker);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Text that gets darker</div>
```